# Ranking list of athletes in a ascended order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

There are total scores of athletes. I want to sort the list by total scores and add the position (place) to `position` field.
In case of equal scores, athletes must share the places, e.g. 3-4 and 3-4 instead of 3 and 4.

```
input date:
 - ABC 10, 
 - BBC 8, 
 - CBC 11,
 - ACD 8

expected output:
 pos,  name, score
- 1,   CBC,  11
- 2,   ABC,  10
- 3-4, BBC,  8
- 3-4, ACD,  8
```

My solution looks a bit complicated, is there any better way?

```
class Athlete {
   private String name;
   private Long totalScore;
   private String position;
}

List<Athlete> athletes = new ArrayList()<>;
...
        int i = 0;
        int rank = 0;
        long score = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Map<Integer, Integer> rankings = new HashMap<>();
        for (Athlete athlete : athletes) {
            ++i;
            if (score != athlete.getTotalScore()) {
                rank = i;
                rankings.put(rank, 1);
            } else {
                rankings.put(rank, rankings.get(rank) + 1);
            }
            athlete.setRank(rank + "");
            score = athlete.getTotalScore();
        }
        rankings.entrySet()
                .stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .forEach(entry -> {
                    int pos = entry.getKey() - 1;
                    String cRank = entry.getKey() + "-" + (pos + entry.getValue());
                    IntStream.range(pos, pos + entry.getValue())
                            .forEach(p -> athletes.get(p).setRank(cRank));
                });
```

What

Comment: Does your solution actually work? If so, what specifically concerns you about the solution? If the solution works, then this might not be the best location for your question as it *may* be a better fit at the [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Note that I said "may" be better there since they have their own rules and regulations on what questions are most appropriate, and it would be wise to check their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) links.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes it works. I'm not asking to improve my solution. I want to know if there's any other better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're required to use streams, but the following is fairly simple:

```
List<Athlete> athletes = Arrays.asList(new Athlete("ABC", 10), new Athlete("BBC", 8),
                                       new Athlete("CBC", 11), new Athlete("ACD", 8));

Collections.sort(athletes, Comparator.comparing(Athlete::getScore).reversed());

for(int j = 0, i = 1; i <= athletes.size(); i++)
{
    if(i == athletes.size() || athletes.get(i).getScore() != athletes.get(j).getScore())
    {
        String pos = (j + 1) + ((j + 1 == i) ? "" : "-" + i);
        while (j < i) athletes.get(j++).setPosition(pos);
    }               
}


for(Athlete a : athletes) System.out.println(a);
```

Output:

```
1 : CBC : 11
2 : ABC : 10
3-4 : BBC : 8
3-4 : ACD : 8
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if this is any better but it works.

```
List<Athlete> athletes = List.of(
        new Athlete("ABC", 10),
        new Athlete("BBC", 8),
        new Athlete("CBC", 11),
        new Athlete("ACD", 7),
        new Athlete("CCD", 7),
        new Athlete("DCD", 7),
        new Athlete("ECD", 5),
        new Athlete("FCD", 2));
```

- First, sort the athlete's scores in reversed order.
- then group the athletes with the same totals in a list, keyed by that total.
- use a LinkedHashMap to preserve the sorted order.

```
Map<Long, List<Athlete>> map = athletes.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator
                .comparingLong(Athlete::getTotalScore).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Athlete::getTotalScore,
                LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

- Now, iterate over the values which are lists of the athletes.
- If the size of the list is a single entry, assign the current position.
- otherwise assign each athlete in the list a range from current position to size of list minus 1.

```
int pos = 1;

int pos = 1;
for(List<Athlete> list : map.values()) {
    int size = list.size();
    for(Athlete ath :list) {
       ath.setPosition(size == 1 ? (pos+"") : (pos + "-" + (size + pos-1)));
    }
    pos += size;
}

map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
1 CBC 11
2 ABC 10
3 BBC 8
4-6 ACD 7
4-6 CCD 7
4-6 DCD 7
7 ECD 5
8 FCD 2
```